# Launching X11 server as non-root user

Tags: debian, x11, xorg

I'm trying to launch an x11 session (or is it an xorg session? I'm not sure) from the command line: `startx &`. I get the following result:

`X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.`

I have `allowed_users=console` set in the `/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config` file so my understanding is that ordinary users should be able to launch an X session from the console. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** I get a slightly different response to the `startx` command over SSH (the output reported above was from a terminal window in an existing x11 environment):

`xauth:  file /home/steve/.Xauthority does not exist
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out that I have to jump to another `tty` screen on the box, login, and issue `startx` from there.

**UPDATE:** Just to clarify, to jump to another `tty` screen, you use the hotkeys (CTRL-ALT-[F1, F2, F3, etc.])